# Why I have this space in my variable? How can I trim that?

Tags: bash

Hi guys I have this line in my ~/.bashrc

```
alias test_echo="echo TEST=$1"
```

I tried:

```
$ test_echo some_string
```

And I got

```
TEST= some_string
```

Why there is a space? How can I trim that?

Thanks

Comment: alias are not functions, that `$1` is the empty string and the space comes from `echo` receiving two parameters, `TEST=` and the parameter you've passed when calling the aliased command

Comment: if you want to use `echo` I'd use a function, otherwise with an alias you can use `printf 'TEST=%s'` to achieve the format you want

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron said in his comment I create a function

```
function () {
    echo "TEST=$1"
}
```